# Why does CodeTypeReference truncate my type with generic parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, codedom

I'm trying to define a base class of type `"foo<a,b,c,d,e>"` in CodeDom, but it comes out as `"foo<a"`

Here is a sample test: T1 and T2 pass but T3 and T4 Fail.

```
T3: Expected string length 14 but was 5. Strings differ at index 5.
  Expected: "foo<a,b,c,d,e>"
  But was:  "foo<a"
  ----------------^
```

--

```
using System.CodeDom;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Strange
    {
        [Test]
        public void T1()
        {
            var name = "foo<a,b,c>";
            var codeTypeParameter1 = new CodeTypeParameter(name);
            var codeTypeReference1 = new CodeTypeReference(codeTypeParameter1);
            Assert.AreEqual(codeTypeParameter1.Name, name);
            Assert.AreEqual(name, codeTypeReference1.BaseType);
        }

        [Test]
        public void T2()
        {
            var name = "foo<a,b,c,d>";
            var codeTypeParameter1 = new CodeTypeParameter(name);
            var codeTypeReference1 = new CodeTypeReference(codeTypeParameter1);
            Assert.AreEqual(codeTypeParameter1.Name, name);
            Assert.AreEqual(name, codeTypeReference1.BaseType);
        }

        [Test]
        public void T3()
        {
            var name = "foo<a,b,c,d,e>";
            var codeTypeParameter1 = new CodeTypeParameter(name);
            var codeTypeReference1 = new CodeTypeReference(codeTypeParameter1);
            Assert.AreEqual(codeTypeParameter1.Name, name);
            Assert.AreEqual(name, codeTypeReference1.BaseType);
        }  

        [Test]
        public void T4()
        {
            var name = "foo<a,b,c,d,e,f>";
            var codeTypeParameter1 = new CodeTypeParameter(name);
            var codeTypeReference1 = new CodeTypeReference(name);
            Assert.AreEqual(codeTypeParameter1.Name, name);
            Assert.AreEqual(name, codeTypeReference1.BaseType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the docs: "If initializing an instance of this class with a string, it is strongly recommended to always use fully qualified types, ..." Also: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/compmod/system/codedom/CodeTypeReference.cs#L372 it probably thinks its a fully qualified type name, and `[` is for arrays and/or type arguments.

Comment: Can you try angle brackets without any spaces `foo<a,b,c,d,e>`

Comment: @CodingYoshi. Yes, that behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this same problem.  While the question is why does it happen (I don't know), I was able to find a work around by using explicit code type references.  i.e.

```
var type1 = new CodeTypeReference("Type1");
var type2 = new CodeTypeReference("Type2");
var genericType = new CodeTypeReference("GenericType");
genericType .TypeArguments.Add(tupleType);
genericType .TypeArguments.Add(returnType);
```